# Recursive Ansible filter in jinja2 template file

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, jinja2, operator-sdk

I have a playbook like this:

```yaml
- name: Testing
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Set things
      set_fact:
        my_things:
          - parameters:
              dog: true
              opts:
                DO_THIS: true
                DO_THAT: "false"
              role: Samba
            action: dance
          - parameters:
              cat: true
              opts:
                DO_THIS: no
                DO_THAT: "yes"
              role: Funk
            action: dance
```

that I want to write in a jinja2 template that looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "test"
data:
  myfile.yml: |+
    ---
    dancers:
    {% for thing in my_things %}
      - {{ thing.action }}:
      {% for key, value in thing.parameters.items() %}
        {% if value is string and not (value) %}
          {{ key }}: "{{ value }}"
        {% elif value is mapping %}
          {{ key }}:
            {{ value | to_nice_yaml | indent(12) -}}
        {% elif value | bool %}
          {{ key }}: {{ (value) }}
        {% elif not value | bool %}
          {{ key }}: {{ (value) }}
        {% else %}
          {{ key }}: {{ value | to_yaml }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This is doing its thing, but it looks extremly ugly and will also break if there is a `mapping` inside of a `mapping`. Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "test"
data:
  myfile.yml: |+
    ---
    dancers:
    {% for thing in my_things %}
      - {{ thing.action }}:
      {% thing.parameters | to_yaml %}
```

This works for `role`, `dog` and `cat` but breaks for `opts` as it is not recursive.

Since I am deploying this configmap using the operator-sdk and a `lookup` filter I cannot use jinja's `env` to write a custom filter.

```yaml
- name: 'Creating v1.ConfigMap'
  community.kubernetes.k8s:
    definition: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_template.yml.j2') }}"
```

Hence, my question would be: Is there any way to inline some python code or alternatively, is there something like a recursive `to_yaml` filter?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question correctly, but the `to_yaml` filter is "recursive" already. It will print everything from the input as yaml, including nested dictionaries, lists etc.

Comment: Thanks - I just realized that the error might have been coming from somewhere else entirely. So with blaming the to_yaml filter I was entirely on the "woodway" as they say in Germany ;)

Comment: @stiller_leser if you got this working, could you answer your own question and mark this resolved?